# In Flutter, how to solve `AnimatedCrossFade` inefficient design?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

A problem with `AnimatedCrossFade` is that you must provide both children, even if only one of them is being displayed.

If one (or both) of those children is complex and heavy, this is not efficient.

I have tried to provide a `Builder` as a child, like this:

```
AnimatedCrossFade(
    firstChild: widget1,
    secondChild: Builder(builder: widget2builder),
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    crossFadeState: toggle ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
),

var widget2builder = (context) {
  print("Building widget 2");
  return Container(),
  );
};
```

However, this prints *`Building widget 2`* right away, even if the first widget is the one being displayed and thus widget 2 is not needed at all.

This is a complete, runnable example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool toggle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    toggle = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var toggleButton = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        child: const Text("Toggle"),
        color: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            toggle = !toggle;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    var widget1 = Container(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 200.0,
      child: const Text(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "
            "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation "
            "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      ),
    );

    var widget2builder = (context) {
      print("Building widget 2.");
      return Container(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 200.0,
        child: const Text(
          "I am ready for my closeup.",
        ),
      );
    };

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            toggleButton,
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text("Some text above."),
                AnimatedCrossFade(
                  firstChild: widget1,
                  secondChild: Builder(builder: widget2builder),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  crossFadeState: toggle ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                ),
                const Text("Some text below."),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you run this, you will see that *`Building widget 2`* is printed to the console, but widget 1 is the one being displayed.

My questions:

- Is there any reason why `AnimatedCrossFade` is building the widget it doesn't use?
- How can I prevent this problem and use `AnimatedCrossFade` efficiently?

Comment: In no situation should a widget be "complex and heavy". What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Widgets that have a lot of widgets inside of them. Widgets that do complex calculations. Widgets that access databases or the network to get info they need to build themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to add to Rémi's answer that sometime after asking this question I've published a package to solve it, called `AnimatedSizeAndFade`:

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_size_and_fade

How does it compare to other similar widgets:

- With AnimatedCrossFade you must keep both the firstChild and secondChild, which is not necessary with AnimatedSizeAndFade.
- With AnimatedSwitcher you may simply change its child, but then it only animates the fade, not the size.
- AnimatedContainer also doesn't work unless you know the size of the children in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavior.

As stated by the dart team, you should expect the `build` method the be called at any times. 
`build` is designed to be cheap and without side effects.

The fact that a widget is built doesn't mean it's rendered on screen. `Opacity` with an opacity of 0 actually shortcuts the painting process (and have other optimizations when completely opaque).

---

If this causes a problem then you should instead use [`AnimatedSwitcher`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) which plays an animation when its child is replaced.